# How to get the text and html returned on selected text

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So I'm using a editing tool on my site and am adding my own button and custom style to toolbar. I have the function that switches between styles and that gets selected text. How do I create a function that gets the html from selected text and finds a certain element like < p > or < img >?

This is what I have so far...

```
init: function( editor ) {

    var config = editor.config,
        lang = editor.lang.format;

    // Gets the list of tags from the settings.
    var tags = []; //new Array();
    tags[0]=["red_font", "Red Font", "Name"];

    // Create style objects for all defined styles.

    editor.ui.addRichCombo( 'dag_wygwam',
        {
            label : "Buttons",
            title :"Buttons",
            voiceLabel : "Buttons",
            className : 'cke_format',
            multiSelect : false,

            panel :
            {
                voiceLabel : lang.panelVoiceLabel
            },

            init : function()
            {
                this.startGroup( "Buttons Functions" );
                for (var this_tag in tags){
                    this.add(tags[this_tag][0];
                }
            },

            onClick : function( value )
            {
                console.log(editor.getSelection().getSelectedText());
                editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );

                switch (value) {
                    case "red_font": value = red_font(editor.getSelection().getSelectedText()); break;
                }                      
               editor.insertHtml(value);
                editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );                        
            }
        });
}
});

function red_font(selection){
}
```

So this red_font function must do the following: fetch the html from the selected text, find the span class in the selected text, and make only the span element red.

Answer (score 0):

```
var theselectedtext = null;
var theselectedelement = null;
document.onmouseup = function(e) {
e = e||event;
// to get the selected text
if (window.getSelection) {
// most browsers
theselectedtext = window.getSelection().toString();
} else {
// IE9
if (document.selection.createRange) {
theselectedtext = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
}
if (theselectedtext != null) {
// get the last clicked element
theselectedelement = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
}
}
```

at any given time, theselectedtext variable will contain the selected text, and theselectedelement variable will contain the selected element.